# SwiftUI - Value of type PhotosSelector has no member imageSelection

Tags: ios, image, swiftui, photo, picker

This piece of code is supposed to let the user pick an image from their device's Photo Library and print whether it was successful, successful with empty value or unsuccessful.

```
struct PhotosSelector: View {
    @State var selectedItems: [PhotosPickerItem] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItems,
                     matching: .images) {
            Text("Select a Photo")
        }
    }
    
    func loadTransferable(from imageSelection: PhotosPickerItem) -> Progress {
        return imageSelection.loadTransferable(type: Image.self) { result in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard imageSelection == self.imageSelection else { return }
                switch result {
                case .success(let image?):
                    print("Success.")
                case .success(nil):
                    print("Success with empty value.")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Failure.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `guard imageSelection == self.imageSelection else { return }` keeps throwing the following error:

> Value of type 'PhotosSelector' has no member 'imageSelection'

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, hope you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without self?
e.g.
`self.imageSelection` -> `imageSelection`
or
`guard imageSelection else { return }`

You are trying to use `imageSelection` from `PhotosSelector` and not from `func loadTransferable`.
Because `PhotoSelector` has no `imageSelection` variable.